# изменение кнопки после галочки в чекбокс

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка "отправить" и есть чекбокс на согласие обработки персональных данных.
Как сделать, чтобы кнопка была неактивна или не нажималась без галочки в чекбоксе.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector(".checkbox").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.querySelector(".btn").disabled = !document.querySelector(".checkbox").checked;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" disabled>Кнопка</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Я согласен с правилами</label>
```

Comment: +1 за корректный ответ и своевременое редактирование вопроса ))

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" disabled>Кнопка</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onChange="document.querySelector('.btn').disabled=(this.checked ? false : true);"> Я согласен с правилами</label>
```

Comment: `....disabled=!this.checked;`

Comment: @Igor, гуд! А еще короче сделать весь код без JQuery реально? Например по этой части document.querySelector('.btn').disabled ?

Comment: Будем ли мы считать вариант в моем ответе "короче"?

Comment: @Igor, будем! Но хотелось бы еще короче, навроде onChange="$('.btn').attr('disabled',!this.checked);". Тот нечастый случай когда мужики меряются у кого короче :)

Answer (score 1):

Без javascript-a:

```css
.btn,.btn-disabled {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

.checkbox:checked~.btn-disabled {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:not(:checked)~.btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="agree">
  <label for="agree"> Я согласен с правилами</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Кнопка</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-disabled" disabled>Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с JQuery (соавтор @Igor)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" disabled>Кнопка</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onChange="$('.btn').attr('disabled',!this.checked);"> Я согласен с правилами</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="bnt" disabled>отправить</button>
    <input onchange="btn(event)" type="checkbox"/> 


function btn(e){
        var btn = document.getElementById('bnt');
        if (e.target.checked) btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
        else btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
```